# creating virtual hard Drive 

Tags: c#

how can I create Virtual Hard Drive (like Z:) that store it's files on physical hard drive (Like C:\Files).

Comment: By writing a device driver. Something you can't do with C#.

Comment: Not expert but it looks like you need to work at kernel level with DDK.

Comment: @dtv & LatinSuD, this definitely doesn't require creating a virtual file system, you can easily map a drive to local paths.

Comment: While the question would better be phrased as "How do I mount a local folder as a virtual hard drive?" I can't imagine why this got a downvote.

Comment: Why the `close` votes, this is a perfectly valid question ?

Comment: Ata, Im not saying to close, im asking why other people have asked to be closed when it seems to be a valid question!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here is C# code to do this directly:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

static class Subst {
    public static void MapDrive(char letter, string path) {
        if (!DefineDosDevice(0, devName(letter), path))
            throw new Win32Exception();
    }
    public static void UnmapDrive(char letter) {
        if (!DefineDosDevice(2, devName(letter), null))
            throw new Win32Exception();
    }
    public static string GetDriveMapping(char letter) {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(259);
        if (QueryDosDevice(devName(letter), sb, sb.Capacity) == 0) {
            // Return empty string if the drive is not mapped
            int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            if (err == 2) return "";
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
        return sb.ToString().Substring(4);
    }


    private static string devName(char letter) {
        return new string(char.ToUpper(letter), 1) + ":";
    }
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool DefineDosDevice(int flags, string devname, string path);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int QueryDosDevice(string devname, StringBuilder buffer, int bufSize);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
        Subst.MapDrive('z', @"c:\temp");
        Console.WriteLine(Subst.GetDriveMapping('z'));
        Subst.UnmapDrive('z');
```

Comment: If the user passes in the drive letter of a hard drive, `sb` will contain something like `\Device\HarddiskVolume2` and the `Substring(4)` will basically return garbage. I'd suggest making sure `sb` starts with `@"\??\"` before returning the `Substring(4)`. If it starts with something else, `""` (same thing you return if the drive doesn't exist at all) seems like a reasonable value to return - there is no SUBSTed drive to get the path of.

Comment: @Hans Passant: the above code will not show any effect when the application is run under admin permissions. i.e. `Run As Admin` tried it in windows 8 and windows 10 as well, however, without admin permissions it the code will show the expected results, a question posted related to subject here, appreciate if you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/q/46663368/323339

Comment: @Jalal Said: This type of mapping is only visible to the user that ran the command. If you run this as admin, the drive will be mapped for the admin. You'll have to run it as yourself to see it in your session.

Answer (score 10):

You can use subst command. 
Use System.Diagnostic.Process to run the subst.exe with desired parameters.

Here is the command syntax:

> Syntax
>
> Associates a path with a drive letter.
>
> ```
> SUBST [drive1: [drive2:]path] 
> SUBST drive1: /D
> ```
>
> drive1:   Specifies a virtual drive to
>   which you want to assign a path.
>
> [drive2:]path Specifies a physical
>   drive and path you want to assign to a
>   virtual drive.
>
> /D Deletes a
>   substituted (virtual) drive.
>
> Type SUBST with no parameters to display a
>   list of current virtual drives.list of current virtual drives.

Comment: Just so you know, this maybe on of the easiest methods. However, Rebooting the computer will revert the mount and remove the virtual drive and put everything back to normal. If you add the entry to autoexec.bat file, the virtual drive can be retained throughout restarts.

Comment: @Ranhiru, you're right, the virtual drive will be reverted on every boot. An easy solution is that the program will call the subst command whenever it start.

Comment: In Windows 7/64, what's the best way to do a permanent "subst" that will be seen by all processes?

Answer (score 1):

Do it the exact same way you would map a network drive, but point it to a folder on the current machine.  The only thing you have to do special is use a UNC path for the local folder.

Here is a [helper class](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/windowsservices/article.php/c12357)

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how to do this in C# but this should help you:

Ive just tested this and works perfect

On my computer have 1 hard drive devised into 2, `C:` & `D:`, going into `D:` i have a folder called Backup, if you right click the folder and click the `Share` Tab, you will see `Network Path`.. On my pc it looks like `\\Robert-home\backup`

I then proceeded to `CMD` and executed the following command

```
NET USE Z: \\Robert-home\backup
```

Witch successfully map the contents of `D:\backup` to `Z:`

Im sure you can complete such a task within C#..

I usually use this method at work for client support to transfer and backup files before new consoles are issued to them.