# Create virtual drive in C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I am searching for a code to create a virtual drive. I came across the DefineDosDevice API Function but I have one big Problem with that Function. I can t change the VolumeLabel of the created Drive.

[creating virtual hard Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753758/creating-virtual-hard-drive)  here is one example. If you use SetVolumeName with that drive you get an error returned.

May anyone has an idea how to do solve my problem?

Comment: Clearly DefineDosDevice() is not what you want, it just creates an alias for a drive letter, it is not a volume.  Windows 7 supports VHD (common in virtual PCs), Windows 8 adds ISO (common for optical drives).  In general, turning a file into a volume is not an innate capability in Windows, it takes a file system driver to do the mapping.  Which are very hard to get right.  Even by the Microsoft guys, it took them a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the volume name of a "DosDevice" because there is no place where it can be stored. A physical volume usually has a hidden meta-data (like `$VOLUME` or so for NTFS) file to store the volume name. No such location exists for a virtual device because it's just an alias for a folder).

Comment: is there any other way to create a virtual drive?