# How to create user with access only to one given folder?

Tags: windows, policy

I need to make "sandbox" to run scripts and applications (PHP, Perl, exe files, Ruby, and so on). But interpreters needs to be accesible to run and only one folder can be accessible to be changed. Also it will be great to allow application to be launched with quotas on hard drive. What do I need to use in this case?

I need solution in C#

Comment: out of the box Windows security and quotas?

Comment: Somebody edited my tags... I need solution in C#. What I need to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just setup windows Security to allow this, select the folder you wish the user to access to and set permissions on it (right click, properties, security). The problem with this approach is you need to find all other folders and revoke access to them if you don't want the user using them (ie EVERYONE and USERS access).

Alternativly have a peek at the [WinJail](http://www.winquota.com/wj/faq.html) package which does as you require. (CHROOT/JAIL implimentation for windows).

Comment: So... Is it right? I need to iterate ALL folders and subfolders and files on all drives to deny access for user. It is not enough to deny access to all root folders except some C:\apptemps\ folder?

Comment: Afraid not, since its a ACL, if you allow a user access to a subdir they get access to that subdir.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create some sort of virtual drive.
Look at this 
[creating virtual hard Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753758/creating-virtual-hard-drive) 
and a csharp library to play with virtual drives
http://dokan-dev.net/en/
Hope this help

Comment: It will be great for one aplication, but I will start approx 400 applications in one time and virtual drives not very good solution for it.I need to have FAST solution. May be minifilter kernel drivers with API for C# applications? It wil be Ideal because I will no need to create users. I will apply my own policies based on process id identification.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a filesystem filter on all file operations and control them this way, but such wide filter will slowdown operations significantly, especially if checks are done in user mode (via callbacks). You can test our [CallbackFilter](http://www.eldos.com/cbflt/) product, which lets you do the above in C#, but be ready for slowness.