# Map ftp to drive C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, ftp

I need to map ftp to drive on c#.

I uses an answer from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753758/creating-virtual-hard-drive), but it works only local folders (I think)

My code:

```
Subst.MapDrive('q', @"ftpServerName");
```

doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure where this `Subst` class comes from, but if it's anything related to the `subst.exe` utility that just allows you to alias a local or SMB directory with a drive letter and I don't believe works with FTP.  In any case, you should elaborate on what you mean when you say your code "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not trivial. The first problem is that FTP is not a filesystem access protocol and it's not possible to implement a full-featured filesystem based on standard FTP commands. Yet for read-only filesystems FTP is ok.

Now, you can't easily map anything remote to a drive letter in Windows. You need to write a kernel-mode virtual filesystem driver. A year or so of work.

Our [Callback File System](http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/) offers a pre-built driver which calls your user-mode code for an actual job. This way you can create a virtual filesystem in C#. We have a sample project, which is a simplified version of our SFTP Net Drive freeware product and which does what you need but via SFTP (SFTP is SSH-based protocol that offers low-level file operations and can be used for a virtual filesystem). But with FTP you still have the above mentioned problem with writes and probably with renames.

Comment: thanks, for ansver! I can open my ftp on windows explorer. all i need - it's only link my ftp folder for easy use!

Comment: @user1616443 What you see in Explorer is not a disk folder but a virtual namespace. You can't have it as a disk available for other applications (some apps can work with virtual namespaces, but most can not).