# How can I create a drive in Windows backed by a custom storage?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, storage

I have a use-case where I need to make a block of storage (think any cloud based storage provider or a Database) available as a *Windows* drive.

I am happy to do the coding but haven't got a clue where to start.

Answer (score 1):

you have to work with Windows Drivers SDK, there are some samples online about this, something "similar" but not 100% saem as what you need is teh RAM drive implementation whcih creates a new drive which uses RAM memory as storage,

have a look here for some source code you can compile in Visual Studio and to see how you have to setup/prepare your machine for Windows drivers development.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/storage/ramdisk

Comment: That looks promising!

Answer (score 0):

See this question:

[creating virtual hard Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753758/creating-virtual-hard-drive)

You would need to create a folder location, probably somewhere in the user's folder tree and map the drive as in the answer in the above link. Then use that folder to sync files with your cloud storage. I doubt you'd want to have the files in memory as you may end up with a drive containing gigabytes of data.