# C# Create virtual disk with Subst command

Tags: c#, drive

I need to create a directory with the letter P (or whatever) so that it is like drive C or D.
After trying different methods, I came to the conclusion that it is best to do this with the help of Subst.
But how to do it in C#. The code I'm using doesn't work. As administrator, does not work either.

`

```
string diskLetter = "P:"; // <---
string path = @"D:\folder path";
 
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "subst",
    Arguments = $"{diskLetter} \"{path}\"",
    Verb = "runas",
    UseShellExecute = true
});
```

`

Comment: Please provide more detailed information. Where is your usage of Subst? What is the exact error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [creating virtual hard Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753758/creating-virtual-hard-drive)

Comment: Windows 10.
Hands through cmd subst turns out, the disk is created.
And C# doesn't work. Tried both console application and windows forms

Comment: Does this answer your question? creating virtual hard Drive – 
Klaus Gütter
 Thank you. I also found this and tried it myself.

Comment: There is no exception, just nothing happens and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend you to use CliWrap libriary, that will improve your work with cli in .NET.

I think, you should check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands) to understand how to use cli (cmd) wrapping in .NET.

So let's try to remake answer in this question to help you.

Don't forget that `subst` is command that requires the admin privileges, so.

```cs
string driveLetter = "P";
string path = "C:\\my\\folder\\path";

Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = $"/C copy subst {driveLetter}: {path}";
startInfo.Verb = "runas";

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: Jeroen Mostert's solution worked immediately. That's why I marked it as a solution.
Thank you too! I'll check out everything you suggested.

Comment: @Lesnik: I can't take credit; I think you'll need to praise the creators of ChatGPT, as the answer has all the hallmarks of being generated by it.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert: Sorry, I don't know what ChatGPT is.
Googled, found out, but did not use.
I would be glad to thank everyone who helped, but I still have a small rating to rate. Alas.
Or I don't understand what it is. Sorry.